# Using hover() method in JQuery to highlight a button in combination with JQuery to click button

Tags: jquery

I have a button on a webpage I am making for myself that accesses a menu I have normally hidden. But I would like the button to highlight when I hover my mouse over it. To satisfy this I use the hover() and click() JQuery methods. The click works fine but when I add the hover it not only doesn't work but it prevents the click event from working as well. The code I am using is as follows,

HTMl

```
<div id="menu"><input src="button.png" class="menuButton" type="image"></div>
<div id="menuBox">(MENU STUFF)</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu { 
        (position code)
      }
#menuBox {
           position: absolute; 
          (position code)
          display:none;
        }
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
function() {
  $('#menu').click(
        function(){
            $('#menuBox').toggle();         
        });
  $('#menu').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).css({"border": "1px solid black";"box-shadow": "1px 1px 1px #000000"});
        }, function(){
            $(this).css('border', 'none');
        });
});
```

If I click on the button(which is the #menu id) then it toggles the display info for the div #menuBox. With the hover() method I change the css for the button giving in shadows and a border to give the appearance of being highlighted.

But like I said, it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone see my mistake?

Comment: `<input src="button.png" class"menuButton" type="image">`, you missed the `=` after `class `.

Comment: Ah thank you. Slopping transcribing =) Fixed

Comment: You can adjust styles using the `:hover` psudeo class in CSS. Is there a reason you don't want to use CSS?

Comment: @EditedContent Can you try adding an `alert("...");` after the `$("#menuBox").toggle();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.menuButton:hover {
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
```

I know you are asking about javascript, but CSS is a more elegant solution in this case as it would work on elements inserted into the DOM after the fact and doesn't require increased load via JS.